# Overriding nimsticks package not working as desired

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, random-numbers

`nimsticks` is a package that makes drawing nim games easier. For example `\nimgame{5,3,4}` generates  three piles of 5,3,4 sticks respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nimsticks}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\nimgame{5,3,4}

\end{document}
```

The command `\onenimstick` can be overrode to replace the default stick with a custom shape. I overrode the stick to a star emoji by adding this line of code.

```
\renewcommand{\onenimstick}{\node at (0,\lift) {\twemoji[height=1cm]{star}};}
```

This replaces the default stick with a star and gives a small horizontal variation to each of them. However, I want to give them a bit more randomness by rotating them so I added rng.

```
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\newcommand{\rng}{\pgfmathrandom{0,90}}
\renewcommand{\onenimstick}{\node at (0,\lift) {\twemoji[height=1cm,angle=\rng]{star}};}
```

The final code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nimsticks}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\newcommand{\rng}{\pgfmathrandom{0,90}}
\renewcommand{\onenimstick}{\node at (0,\lift) {\twemoji[height=0.3cm,angle=\rng]{star}};}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\nimgame{5,3,4}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I get an `Undefined control sequence` error when I try to add rng. The first two steps work fine. What is wrong with my rng code?

Comment: Note that you forgot `\usepackage{twemojis}` in your MWE. Also `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is no longer needed, utf8 is the default in LaTeX since 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Like many `pgfmath` operations, `\pgfmathrandom` only performs the operation, it doesn't expose the result. For this the macro `\pgfmathresult` is used, which always contains the value of the most recent `\pgfmathXXX` call. Therefore, to get the actual value, you need `\pgfmathrandom{x,y}\pgfmathresult`, or with the macro defined in the question `\rng\pgfmathresult`.

In this particular case `angle=` expects a concrete value, not a chain of processing. This means that `angle=\rng\pgfmathresult` will not work, and neither will `\newcommand{\rng}{\pgfmathrandom{0,90}\pgfmathresult}` with `angle=\rng`. To decouple the random number *generation* from the *usage* you can call `\rng` first at the start of the node and then use `\pgfmathresult` as value for `angle=`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nimsticks}
\usepackage{twemojis}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\newcommand{\rng}{\pgfmathrandom{0,90}}
\renewcommand{\onenimstick}{\node at (0,\lift) {\rng\twemoji[height=0.3cm,angle=\pgfmathresult]{star}};}

\begin{document}

\nimgame{5,3,4}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]